# How to count throttled requests on a per endpoint in Locust?

Tags: python, load-testing, metrics, locust

I am currently creating a custom TUI dashboard to extend the data I can see in the terminal with [locust](https://locust.io/).

Currently, I am using the following logic to capture all data:

```py
@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    if isinstance(environment.runner, (MasterRunner, LocalRunner)):
        stream_handler = prepare_handler()
        gevent.spawn(Dashboard(stream_handler).run, environment)
```

I can then use the `environment.runner.stats.entries` data to get all `RequestStats` data and place them into a custom table.

One issue I have is getting throttled requests into this table.

I am using the following in the `HttpUser` `task` to ensure all responses with status 429 count towards failures and add an new attribute that could be used downstream:

```py
    @task
    def endpoint(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.client.get("/some/url/", catch_response=True, *args, **kwargs) as response:
            if response.status_code == 429:
                response.failure("Throttled!")
                if entry := self.environment.runner.stats.entries.get((url, method)):
                    if not getattr(entry, "throttled"):
                        entry.throttled = 1
                    else:
                        entry.throttled += 1
```

However, the `environment.runner.stats.entries` values do not contain the new `throttled` attribute downstream that is parsed via the `on_locust_init` listener.

I am wondering if there is a way to add custom stats as requests are processed so I can consume they elsewhere for creating custom tables?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is keep track of your custom metrics and stats separately and then use [Events](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.worker_report) to include them in the workers' reports to the master. You can then have the master pull them out when reported and include them in your terminal output.

The Locust repo has an example of this here:

https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/908c414dc04c12315ca5ecfd7851c9e42b2713ba/examples/events.py#L48

```
stats = {"content-length": 0}


@events.init.add_listener
def locust_init(environment, **kwargs):
    """
    We need somewhere to store the stats.
    On the master node stats will contain the aggregated sum of all content-lengths,
    while on the worker nodes this will be the sum of the content-lengths since the
    last stats report was sent to the master
    """
    if environment.web_ui:
        # this code is only run on the master node (the web_ui instance doesn't exist on workers)
        @environment.web_ui.app.route("/content-length")
        def total_content_length():
            """
            Add a route to the Locust web app, where we can see the total content-length
            """
            return "Total content-length received: %i" % stats["content-length"]a


@events.request.add_listener
def on_request(request_type, name, response_time, response_length, exception, context, **kwargs):
    """
    Event handler that get triggered on every request.
    """
    stats["content-length"] += response_length


@events.report_to_master.add_listener
def on_report_to_master(client_id, data):
    """
    This event is triggered on the worker instances every time a stats report is
    to be sent to the locust master. It will allow us to add our extra content-length
    data to the dict that is being sent, and then we clear the local stats in the worker.
    """
    data["content-length"] = stats["content-length"]
    stats["content-length"] = 0


@events.worker_report.add_listener
def on_worker_report(client_id, data):
    """
    This event is triggered on the master instance when a new stats report arrives
    from a worker. Here we just add the content-length to the master's aggregated
    stats dict.
    """
    stats["content-length"] += data["content-length"]
```

In case it's not clear, `data` is a dictionary and you can add whatever you want to it and it will be passed to the master. Your custom data can be in whatever structure you want, but if you're dealing with anything more than a single custom value it's probably easiest to keep it in a dictionary. For example, you could either use a single variable `throttled` as an int that only counts the total of times a 429 was returned, or it could be a dictionary where you keep track of each endpoint that was throttled however many times, like `throttled = {"/some/url": 1}`.