# How to get time to first byte with locust load test?

Tags: load-testing, locust

Im doing load testing of an http endpoint using locust. How can I get Time to First Byte(TTFB) value here?

Answer (score 1):

Locust doesn't provide this metric out of the box, you can [measure it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76208676/how-to-count-throttled-requests-on-a-per-endpoint-in-locust/76211765#76211765) and if needed [show the TTFB in web report](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#extending-web-ui)

Alternatively you can switch to another load testing tool like [Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-vs-locust) which provides TTFB metric out of the box, in JMeter world it's called **[Latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)**.